# SQL - Nome de coluna com o ano atual (dinamicamente)

Tags: sql

Olá!

Já pesquisei bastante, entendi como definir dinamicamente o nome de uma coluna através de uma variável, mas não consegui fazer isso quando a variável tem um número, mesmo que esteja como string!

Preciso definir o nome de uma coluna dinamicamente para que corresponda ao ano atual e ao ano anterior, para isso pensei em usar uma variável:

```
DECLARE @AnoAtual varchar(4) = ltrim(str(year(getdate())))

DECLARE @AnoAnterior varchar(4) = ltrim(str(year(getdate())-1))

Select
    Sum(case Ano when @AnoAtual then Faturamento else 0.00 end) as 
@AnoAtual,
    Sum(case Ano when @AnoAnterior then Faturamento else 0.00 end) as 
@Antoanterior
From....
```

Já tentei colocar a consulta em uma variável e usar o Execute() mas também não funcionou.

Se eu colocar as '2022' funciona, mas as @AnoAtual não!

Alguns exemplos:

Sim, usando o MS SQL Server.

Fiz alguns exemplos:

```
Declare @Ano0 varchar(10) = ltrim(str(year(getdate()))) 
Declare @Ano1 varchar(10) = ltrim(str(year(getdate())-1))

Select @Ano0, @Ano1 --OK

Select 1000 as '2021', 1100 as '2022' --Ok

Select 1000 as @Ano0, 1100 as @Ano1 --erro

Declare @Consulta varchar(max)
Set @Consulta = 'Select 1000 as "2021", 1100 as "2022"'
Exec(@Consulta) --ok

Set @Consulta = 'Select 1000 as ' + @Ano0 + ', 1100 as ' +@Ano1
Exec(@Consulta) --ERRO
```

(1 linha afetada)
Sintaxe incorreta próxima a '2022'.

Sou novato no mundo SQL, agradeço a paciência!!

Obrigado!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: vc está utilizando o SQL Server? se estiver vai ser necessário montar a consulta dinamicamente (em uma variável como você disse), e nesse caso é melhor você postar essa versão do seu código e detalhes do que ocorreu ao executar

Comment: Sim, usando o MS SQL Server.

Fiz alguns exemplos:
```
    Declare @Ano0 varchar(10) = ltrim(str(year(getdate()))) 
    Declare @Ano1 varchar(10) = ltrim(str(year(getdate())-1))

    Select @Ano0, @Ano1

    Select 1000 as '2021', 1100 as '2022' --Ok

    Select 1000 as @Ano0, 1100 as @Ano1 --erro

    Declare @Consulta varchar(max)
    Set @Consulta = 'Select 1000 as "2021", 1100 as "2022"'
    Exec(@Consulta) --ok

    Set @Consulta = 'Select 1000 as ' + @Ano0 + ', 1100 as ' +@Ano1
    Exec(@Consulta) --erro
```

(1 linha afetada)
Sintaxe incorreta próxima a '2022'.

Comment: Como vc está utilizando um número como alias, vai ser necessário acrescentar delimitadores em volta do alias. Repare que no código em que você colocou o alias manualmente, você utilizou aspas duplas como delimitador e funcionou, já o código com a variável não tem os delimitadores

Comment: Acho que encontrei a solução! Além da questão dos delimitadores, uma mesma variável não pode ser usada nas condições e no nome da coluna!
Vou editar a pergunta e colocar a solução lá (nos comentários não cabe!).
Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

A questão é que não se pode usar a mesma variável para uma condição da consulta e também para o nome da coluna!

Assim funcionou:

```
Declare @AnoAnterior varchar(10) = ltrim(str(year(getdate())-1))
Declare @AnoAtual varchar(10) = ltrim(str(year(getdate()))) 
Declare @Ano1 varchar(10) = ltrim(str(year(getdate())-1))
Declare @Ano0 varchar(10) = ltrim(str(year(getdate()))) 
Declare @Consulta varchar(max)

Set @Consulta = 'Select #Parte1.nmes, #Parte1.Mês,
    Sum(case #Parte1.ano when ' +@AnoAnterior+ ' then Faturamento else 0.00 end) as [' + @Ano1 + '],
    Sum(case #Parte1.ano when ' +@AnoAtual+ ' then Faturamento else 0.00 end)as [' + @Ano0 + ']
From
    #Parte1
Group by
    #Parte1.nmes, #Parte1.Mês
Order by 1'
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Pelo que sei não existe essa limitação. No seu código, as variáveis estão sendo utilizadas em um comando para atribuir um valor (string) para uma outra variável, e ao executar a consulta o comando (string) já está pronto e as variáveis citadas não são mais utilizadas. Acho que você teria que postar o seu código que utiliza a mesma variável 2 vezes e a respectiva mensagem de erro para que seja analisada.